# Is it possible to not back up some of the files saved in nsdefault?

Tags: ios, backup, nsuserdefaults

I used `NSDefault` in my app to backup some images and got rejected because it uses 6mb of storage.

Can anyone help me add the donotbackup attribute into it? I would like to keep userdefault directory if possible so old users don't lose their images. Any help would be really appreciated :)

My current code is:

to save:

```
- (IBAction)d1p:(id)sender {
  lbl1.text=txt1.text; [txt1 setAlpha:0];
  NSString *savestringln1 = lbl1.text;
  NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  [defaults setObject:savestringln1 forKey:@"savedstringlbl1"];[defaults synchronize];    
  [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

To load:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *loadstringlbl1 = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedstringlbl1"];
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to back up images? NSUserDefaults isn't really meant for that.

Why not try adding [iCloud support](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/index.php) instead?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to stop something from not being stored in UserDefaults is to just not put it in User Defaults, I am not sure what you mean by backup, you are just duplicating images on the device in two different formats. If the image is on your file system you can store the path to the image in User Defaults if thats useful to you. If you are trying to prevent unintentional deletion can you just mark the 'deleted' images has hidden from the user in some way, a flag, moved to a different location perhaps. You also might want to look into CoreData that can deal with larger amounts of data ad do things like have non serialised properties and such, but that is still just storing your data on the device.